# How can I store user data after login without having to query the database to show this data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to store the user ID, his company ID and name, in a way I won't have to query the database on every postback.

I know I have options like: ViewData, TempData or auth cookie, but, are there any better solution?

Best regards,

Juliano Nunes

Comment: Best is hard to measure. But Session often works. Until it doesn't. Then you spill out into cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASP.NET Profile Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) mechanism looks like a thing you're looking for - especially if you're already using Membership/Role providers.

More generic article on Profile properties: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a classic use of [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> ASP.NET session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application. HTTP is a stateless protocol. This means that a Web server treats each HTTP request for a page as an independent request. The server retains no knowledge of variable values that were used during previous requests. ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during a limited time window as a session, and provides a way to persist variable values for the duration of that session. By default, ASP.NET session state is enabled for all ASP.NET applications.