# HttpContext.User is getting set correctly, then is lost/replaced by next request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have implemented a custom [`AuthCheckAttribute`](http://pastebin.com/akwBxe5G) and used it globally in my application.

I have verified that control flow is correct and the `AllowAnonymousAttribute` is being respected properly.

In my Login action handler I set the current `User` as follows:

```
//This user is an NHibernate entity representing a user of the
//app. AuthUser takes the Identity.Name from here.
HttpContext.User = AuthUser.CreateAuthUser(user);
```

If the username:password combination is valid, `AuthUser.CreateAuthUser()` returns an `IPrincipal` with an `IIdentity` that returns `true` for `IsAuthenticated`.

After having set this, the Login action handler redirects to the page the user was originally going to, and now in `AuthCheckAttribute.OnAuthentication()` method, `context.HttpContext.User` is set to an instance of `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal` (and `IsAuthenticated` returns false) and not to `AuthUser` as I set in my Login handler.

What am I doing wrong? The problem seems to be that the `User` I set in Login action handler is lost/replaced by the time execution reaches `AuthCheckAttribute.OnAuthentication()` again.

I have a classes `AuthUser : IPrincipal` and `AuthIdentity : IIdentity`. A call to `AuthUser.CreateAuthUser(user)` instantiates the `AuthUser` and `AuthIdentity` classes correctly, so no issues there.

Configuration: MVC5, .Net 4.5

Comment: Using `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal` seems very wrong here.

Comment: @leppie I am setting `User` to an instance of `AuthUser`. However by next time `AuthCheckAttribute.OnAuthentication()` is called, the `User` has been replaced. This is the problem I am seeking a solution to. No idea why/how/when it happens.

Comment: Why are you expecting the user to be 'remembered' after a redirect? The `HttpContext` contains information about the **current request**, it is not a place where information can be stored so you can use it at the next request. A redirect means a new request. You need a cookie, the session, or something else, to 'remember' data over multiple request.

Comment: @Maarten Then how does authentication (enforcement) using a filter work? I need to remember for the entire session that the user has authenticated successfully once. Are you suggesting setting the `User` in the `Session`? That was what I was doing in an earlier, filter-less implementation.

Comment: You can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077221/how-can-i-store-user-data-after-login-without-having-to-query-the-database-to-sh) Q&A. I'm not sure what you mean by 'filter-less'. If you want to use the session, the session is specific for the logged on user.

Comment: @Maarten By 'filter-less' I mean every action method would begin by invoking a method to enforce authentication (I knew that was a bad way to do it; didn't know about filters at the time). By storing (and checking!) the credentials in `Session`, I get the semantics I want: while the session is valid, user isn't asked to re-authenticate. But is that the "correct" thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

Session is not necessary. You can store an HTTP only cookie in the browser with the encrypted user id. In your filter, check for this cookie and use the stored user id to reload your user and set it in the HttpContext.